# How come this is possible in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is this

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            newView.transform = afterAnimationTransform
        })
```

and this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1){
            newView.transform = afterAnimationTransform
        }
```

equivalent? and if yes, what is this feature called? and does it only work for the last parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called *trailing closures*, and yes these expressions are equivalent, the second is a shorthand. Read about it in *Swift 2.1 Programming Language*.

Comment: and to answer the very last question: yes, only for the last parameter.